# Computing correlation matrix faster in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I've identified as the bottleneck of my code the following operation on a given Pandas DataFrame df.

```
df.corr()
```

I was wondering whether there exist some drop-in replacements to speed this step up?

Thank you!

Comment: maybe try `numpy.corrcoef`... ?  eg. `pd.DataFrame(np.corrcoef(df.to_numpy(), rowvar=False))`

Comment: Pandas is already nicely optimized. The only possible speedup is to directly use the underlying numpy arrays (possible small optimization) or to completly change the storage organization if relevant. Hard to say more with so little context...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You might try [`numpy.corrcoef`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.corrcoef.html) instead:

```
pd.DataFrame(np.corrcoef(df.values, rowvar=False), columns=df.columns)
```

#### Example Timings

```
# Setup
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000, 1000))

df.corr()
# 15 s ± 225 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

pd.DataFrame(np.corrcoef(df.values, rowvar=False), columns=df.columns)
# 24.4 ms ± 299 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: Yes, this indeed offers much faster computation. Thanks!